# How to delete a static mutex object

Tags: c++, static, mutex

I have a mutex defined as static and used by two threads in order to access to certain function. Since it is static, how should I delete during the finalization phase? Is it okay if I write the following in the base class destructor which is called by each derived class object.

```
pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mutex);
```

Comment: How do you allocate this mutex? Are you even allocating is?

Comment: It is defined statically in the base class: static pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;

Comment: So its a local variable, you dont need to delete it. You are passing it to your thread by reference?

Is this mutex defined inside a member function of the object or is it a property of this object? (I understood it was a local function defined in a member function by your previous answer)

Comment: Don't bother, unless on your platform a mutex has some dynamically-allocated resources and your platform also fails to clean up after process exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper struct destroy it for you at the right time.

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;

struct MutexDestroyer {
  ~MutexDestroyer() {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  }
};

static MutexDestroyer mutexDestroyer;
```

When `mutexDestroyer` is destroyed its destructor  will destroy the mutex for you.

Later you can improve it to became a full RAII struct, moving the mutex variable to it and initializing it at the constructor, then create helper functions to lock and unlock the mutex.

Comment: To be picky, this is NOT Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation (RAII), since you're not creating the mutex at initialisation. Better yet would be to declare it inside the `MutexDestroyer`class (which should then change its name) and correctly implement all object-resource mapping stuff. (allow mutex creation upon construction, disallow copying, permit moving and assignment, ...)

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Indeed. I edited the answer to clear this point, thanks.